# Мне нужно добавить расстояние между текстом и свойством underline для этого текста

Tags: css, scss, hover, style

У меня есть заголовк-ссылка, и при наведении она должна иметь свойство подчеркивания как на изображении ниже;
При наведении я даю свойство text-decoration: underline solid 1px $green;
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И у меня получаеться такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно добавить расстояния между текстом и свойсвтом underline!

Comment: попробуйте заменить на `border-bottom + padding-bottom`

Comment: Вообще, это свойство называется [text-underline-offset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset)

Comment: @teran у меня 2 строки текста, border будет давать подчеркивание нижней части текста

Comment: если элемент инлайн, то будет у каждой строки

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov Спасибо, это то что мне и нужно было

Comment: @teran не выходит, это у меня целостная ссылка, и если я задам display: inline-block то это ничем не повлияет на подчеркивание

Comment: @teran, все понял, нужно обернуть текст в span и дать ему inline, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
p {
  max-width: 200px;
  text-underline-offset: 4px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<p>Inflammation of the thyroid i what should i watch out for?</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо, ответ был дан верно

Comment: Интересная [поддержка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-underline-offset#browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

Ну или `border-bottom` и `padding-bottom`

```css
p {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 175%;
}

p > span {
  display: inline;
  border-bottom: 1px solid aqua;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Inflammation of the thyroid i what should i watch out for?</span></p>
```

Comment: А если в 2 строки текст?

Comment: @RomanVinichenko, всё хорошо, добавил ограничение по ширине, чтобы продемонстрировать)

Comment: так хорошо, работает. А мне нужно чтобы этот елемент был блочным, тогда как быть?

Comment: @RomanVinichenko, спан внутри должен быть инлайновый, чтобы учитывались строки

Comment: да, работает, спасибо, 
а как отметить в комментарии твое имя: я ввожу @De.Minov, и ничего не происходит

Comment: @RomanVinichenko, точную механику этого не знаю, но вроде как это не работает если собеседника двое, либо когда адресовано автору сообщения.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130158/discussion-between-roman-vinichenko-and-de-minov).